# How to get a cylinder effect (2D) Progress Bar using Qt programming?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprogressbar

How to change the colors of the progressbar? Say 40% to red, 20% to green and 40% to yellow etc.
I have tried using StyleSheets, but I found that it works only for Flat Progress Bars , not for the 2D bars.

[image]

Comment: please post what you have done so far too

Comment: How many dimensions would a progress bar be in if not 2?

Comment: Have you tried something like different Qt themes? I think it is up to the end user how exactly it will look like.

Comment: @NickA It seems his intention is 2½D presentation of cylinder. Unable to find the [½] key on his keyboard, he left at it out in the title which leaded to the confusion...

Comment: @Schefd makes perfect sense, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: IMHO, there are multiple ways to achieve this in Qt: 1. You may derive [`QProgressBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html) and overload the paint method. 2. You may [create a custom `QStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#creating-a-custom-style) where you override the rendering of the progress bar.

Comment: @Nilabja Currently I have used QPainter to create a Progress bar by using shapes. I dont know whether it is the right idea ... But I am able to draw two ellipses and lines (horizontally arranged )which gives a cylinder effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to generate this effect we draw elliptical, for this we could help us of `QPainterPath` to give it form, and we put the cover that is an ellipse as shown below:

**progressbar2d.h**

```
#ifndef PROGRESSBAR2D_H
#define PROGRESSBAR2D_H

#include <QProgressBar>

class ProgressBar2D : public QProgressBar
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ProgressBar2D(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ProgressBar2D();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

private:
    void draw(QPainter *painter, QRect rect, int w);
    void drawEllipticalRectangle(QPainter *painter, QRect rect, int w);
};

#endif // PROGRESSBAR2D_H
```

**progressbar2d.cpp**

```
#include "progressbar2d.h"
#include <QPainter>

ProgressBar2D::ProgressBar2D(QWidget *parent): QProgressBar(parent)
{
}

ProgressBar2D::~ProgressBar2D()
{
}

void ProgressBar2D::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    int borde = height()/10;

    draw(&painter,
         QRect(borde, borde, width()-2*borde, height()-2*borde),
         2*borde);

    painter.drawText(rect(),  Qt::AlignCenter, QString("%1").arg(value()));

}

void ProgressBar2D::draw(QPainter *painter, QRect rect, int w)
{

    int w_percentage = 2*w + value()*(rect.width()-2*w)/maximum();

    painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor("#81C253")));
    drawEllipticalRectangle(painter,
                            QRect(rect.topLeft(), QSize(w_percentage, rect.height()) ),
                            w);

    painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor("#C3DDB1")));
    drawEllipticalRectangle(painter,
                            QRect(QPoint(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(w_percentage-2*w, 0)),
                                  QSize(rect.width()-w_percentage+2*w, rect.height()) ),
                            w);

    painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor("#77896C")));
    painter->drawEllipse(QRect( rect.topLeft() + QPoint(rect.width()-2*w, 0) , QSize(2*w, rect.height())));

}


void ProgressBar2D::drawEllipticalRectangle(QPainter *painter, QRect rect, int w)
{
    painter->translate(rect.topLeft());

    QPainterPath path;

    path.moveTo(w, 0);
    path.arcTo(QRectF(0, 0, 2*w, rect.height()), 90, 180);
    path.lineTo(rect.width()-w, rect.height());

    path.arcTo(QRectF(rect.width()-2*w, 0, 2*w, rect.height()), 270, -180);
    path.lineTo(w, 0);
    painter->drawPath(path);

    painter->translate(-rect.topLeft());
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "progressbar2d.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ProgressBar2D w;

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(&w);

    QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&w](){
        w.setValue((w.value()+1)%(1 + w.maximum()));
    });
    timer->start(100);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I miste say, I've been watching this for two minutes straight, it's really quite hypnotic. Now I want only cylindrical progress bars.

Comment: I do not understand. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc: how to change the size of the window? setFixedSize is not working here

Comment: Which window, I don't understand?

Comment: @eyllanesc: I did not understand this line in your code,                             int w_percentage = 2*w + value()*(rect.width()-2*w)/maximum()                  could u tell me about it?

Comment: Which line? explicate better Please.

Comment: I mean the Main Window

Comment: If you realize the covers are ellipses of height h and width w.

Comment: In the progressbar2d.cpp within the draw() there i this line                                                              int w_percentage = 2*w + value()*(rect.width()-2*w)/maximum()

Comment: If you encapsulate the cylinder in a rectangle, that is the rectangle that passed to the draw function, and the width of the ellipses on the side faces is w.

Comment: The part that shows the percentage must paint a part of the cylinder, and that is the calculation to know which part to paint, with a little geometry you can understand.